# How can I add a dynamic variable to a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, counting

[this is my output generated. As you can see the JTextField isn't being modified according to the totalValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKVYH.png)

[image]

I'm a beginner at Java and I need help on this matter; I'm doing a POS system using a JTable.

I'm  having difficulty getting the correct total when adding the cost (column) together, but I do not have any errors.

My main problem at the moment is: how can I add a dynamic variable a jtextfield. As in, when I edit in the quantity column a digit, how can I get the new total displayed in the jtextfield. My jtextfield (totalField) is never being updated.

Here is a piece of my code;

```
   public class EditableTable extends JPanel {

   private JTextField filterField = new JTextField();
   private JButton filterButton = new JButton("Filter");
   public JTextField totalField = new JTextField(10);


   private JScrollPane scroll;
   public JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
   public JPanel filterPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());  
   public JPanel receiptPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
   public JPanel transactionPanel = new JPanel();
   JPanel cashPanel = new JPanel();
   JPanel totalPanel = new JPanel();

   private TableModelListener tableModelListener;


   ProductsTableModel model = new ProductsTableModel();
   final JTable table = new JTable(model);

   Double total;
   double totalValue; 
   double payment;

   public JLabel cashLab = new JLabel("Cash");
   public JTextField cashInput = new JTextField(10);

   public JLabel totalLab = new JLabel("Total");

   public JLabel changeLab = new JLabel("");

   public JButton confirmButton = new JButton("Confirm");
   public double change;


public EditableTable(){


    table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new CheckBoxModelListener());
    // final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
    final TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(table.getModel());
    table.setRowSorter(rowSorter);


    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 700));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    KeyStroke tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_TAB,0);
    InputMap map = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
    map.put(tab, "selectNextRowCell");


    scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

    filterPanel.add(new JLabel("Specify a word to match: "), BorderLayout.WEST);
    filterPanel.add(filterField, BorderLayout.CENTER);






    filterField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
            String text = filterField.getText();

            if(text.trim().length() == 0){
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
            }else{
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
            String text = filterField.getText();

            if(text.trim().length() == 0){
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
            }else{
                rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    });

    panel.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(filterPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    cashPanel.add(cashLab);
    cashPanel.add(cashInput);
    receiptPanel.add(cashPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

    cashInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            payment = Double.parseDouble(cashInput.getText());
            change = payment - totalValue;
            changeLab.setText("" + change);
            System.out.println("Change" + change);
        }
    });


    receiptPanel.add(new JLabel("Change " + change), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    totalPanel.add(totalLab);
    totalPanel.add(totalField);
    receiptPanel.add(totalPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

   table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){
       @Override
       public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent ev){
           if(ev.getColumn() == 3|| ev.getColumn() == 4){
               calculateTotal();
            }
        }
    });


}

//Simple method to calculate the total and set it to the JTextField
public void calculateTotal(){
    double total = 0d;
    int numOfRows = table.getRowCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++){
        Object cost = table.getValueAt(i,5);
        if(cost instanceof Number){
            total += ((Number)cost).doubleValue();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total" + total);

    totalField.setText(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(total));
    System.out.println("I DID IT");
}


}
```

Any help is really really appreciated

This is my latest update! I think I might have a problem in my **receiptPanel**, where the **totalField** is concerned.

Comment: Maybe set the  totalValue = 0, before looping the rows...

Comment: it still doesn't work: when adding: 2.65 + 5.9, it gives me a totalValue of 11.2

Comment: Have you put totaleValue = 0; before your loop, then I suggest I nice System.out.println("row: " + i + " cost=" + cost); before the totalValue+=cost; and you see what it is doing...

Comment: oh god! it actually worked. the totalValue value is working perfectly now! thankyou so so much.

Comment: by any chance, do you have any idea how to solve my other problems?

Comment: I hope you figured out why the totaleValue did not work before.... hint... it was not zero when you started to sum it...

Comment: When it works decide whether to post your solution as an answer (and accept it), if you think your question can be useful for others otherwise delete the question...

Comment: yes, i figured it was because it wasn't starting from zero.

Comment: but the jtextfield part still hasn't worked yet. the jtextfield just keeps on staying blank the whole time.

Comment: Sorry you need to set it after your loop....when you got the totalValue after the famous for loop do: totalField.setEditable(false);totalField.setText(" " + totalValue);totalField.setEditable(false);

Comment: To understand is that the 'public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)' is called when you edit the table, you need to set the field from here (otherwise when is the code setting the value called?)...,

Comment: empty piece of code generating 12 comments, for better help sooner post an SSCCE / mcve, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable /XxxTableModel in local variable

Comment: it still doesn't affect it. ive tried seeing whether the totalField.setText("0.00"); works and it does. Now I have to figure out why the totalValue isn't making any effect on it. thanks a lot

Comment: override getValueAt instead of using TableModelListener (isn't designated to change value in JTable / XxxTableModel, as notifier to notify about changes out of the JTable)

Comment: ive edited a link showing my output generated.

Comment: i will be displaying this question as solved for future users

Comment: @Lizzy Farrugia move the  totalField.setText(" " + totalValue); inside if(column == 3 || column == 4){} statmenet (at the end), and it will probably work, mKorble is correct this would not be the correct way of developing and application like this, I'm just trying to make your code run... if you like to post an answer I suggest you study mKorbel solution and you will find that there is a better way, instead of model.setValueAt(total, row, 5); you can return the value of column 5 as the multiplication of 3*4 if you overide the getValueAt metod

Comment: @Lizzy Farrugia voting to close this question

Comment: i have already put it in there. the total jtextfield still isnt displaying anything

Comment: still, doesnt make any effect

Comment: @PetterFriberg will it be easier to use jlabels instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To many comments I post an answer so that you see how TableModel and listener are used.

```
    table = new JTable();
    //I override the getValueAt see @mKorbel comments so that columns 5
    //return the value of 3*4 (you should not to calculate and set this from   
    //the listener, setting the value will recall the listener again)
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel() {

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
            if (column == 5) {
                Object price = super.getValueAt(row, 3);
                Object quantity = super.getValueAt(row, 4);
                if (price instanceof Number && quantity instanceof Number) {
                    return ((Number) price).doubleValue() * ((Number) quantity).intValue();

                }
                return 0d;
            }
            return super.getValueAt(row, column);
        }

    });

    //I use the listener to understand if column 3 or 4 is changed
    //to recalculate my totale. I have also added code to detect inseration/delation of rows.
    table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent ev) {
            switch(ev.getType()){
            case TableModelEvent.UPDATE:
                if (ev.getColumn() == 3 || ev.getColumn() == 4) {
                    calculateTotale();
                }
                return;
            case TableModelEvent.INSERT:
            case TableModelEvent.DELETE:
                calculateTotale();
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}

//Simple metod to calculate the total and set it to the JTextField.
public void calculateTotale() {
    double tot = 0d;
    int numOfRows = table.getRowCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++) {
        Object cost = table.getValueAt(i, 5);
        if (cost instanceof Number) {
            tot += ((Number) cost).doubleValue();
        }
    }
    totalField.setText(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(tot));
    System.out.println("I DID IT!!");
}
```

Note this is not copy and past code, its an brief code example to make you understand of JTable can work.

If you see in the console **I DID IT!!** and the `JTextField` does not change, the totalField is not the totalField you belive it is!... I guess could be; that you are doing `new JTextField()`, adding it to layout and then you are doing `new JTextField()` again (this would change its reference).

Comment: ive skimmed through it, and made a couple of changes in my original code, but the JTextField still won't change. also there is no setValueAt method for the cost

Comment: i really appreciate your time and help :)

Comment: With this code you don't need setValue for cost (see getValueAt() in override, its a trick ; ). If the JTextField does not change and you see the  System.out.println("I DID IT!!"); my guess is that you added another JTextField to your layout..

Comment: can it be the case that my receiptPanel isn't reaching the modified totalValue but a blank totalValue?

Comment: i've realized something, which Im hoping with your further expertise to manage; so when referring to the above code, when coding totalField.setText("" + totalValue) in the tableModelListener, nothing will be displayed in the JTextField. When coding totalField.setText("" + totalValue) exactly after public void tableModelListener{ that can modify the JTextBox, the only problem is that till then totalValue doesnt contain the total. After table.getModel ... again nothing basically happens.

Comment: totalField.setText("" + totalValue) needs to be called, and if called it should always work (only way that i see that it will not work correctly is strange thread outside the swing context but this is not the case)... if you  see  System.out.println("I DID IT!!"); and the text is not changed in the totalField, it probably depends on the fact that totalField is not the totalField you belive it is.. maybe for example you have  2 new JTextField()....

Comment: I've edited it, mind pls checking my receiptPanell (which is then called by my main class, to be displayed). I see System.out.println("I DID IT");

Comment: There is no problem with the JTextField in this class, check the main class, what referenze do you have to totalField, I see its public!! why??, try to make it private so you have error on other code changing it..... Your problem is in othercode

Comment: as for the "othercode" from the other class, I just have; public JComponent getSouth(){
        JPanel southPane = new JPanel();
        southPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        EditableTable r = new EditableTable();
        southPane.add(r.receiptPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        //other code
        
        return southPane;
    
      
      
        
    }

Comment: Heyy! it worked :D:D:D:D let me post my new code, i changed the jtextfield to static and the others to private, as you said. omg Im so happy. Above I have edited the new code. Thank you so so much with everything

Comment: I did not say static... I wanted everybody private..., why static??... what reference are you using in other classes?... well if you are happy I'am